# PHP MySQL UPDATE and SUBTRACT

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query on PHP:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ead_modulos SET slides = slides - 1 WHERE id_modulo = '$id_modulo';");
```

Everytime i run it, it subtracts 2 from slides, so if i have 2 slides and I run this code once, it ends with 0 slides.

I added an output to this query to check if it was being executed 2 times, and it is not, the code runs once and subtracts 2, can anyone help?

edit: I have this other query wich works just fine when adding slides.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ead_modulos SET slides = slides + 1 WHERE id_modulo = '$id_modulo'");
```

edit2: I have tried the query on a blank page with just the db connection, it worked just fine, so the problem is, the code runs 2 times, and i have absolutely no idea why it does that, when i add a slide, it works fine, when i delete a slide it`s like the page loads twice and execute the code twice.

Comment: This code can only subtract 1 (at most) from any given row.  If it is subtracting 2, either it is being called twice or there is a trigger on the table doing the second subtraction or you are misunderstanding the final value.

Answer (score 0):

I agree your code must be run twice.Check it out carefully,and set an echo below this code to give out messages,and see if it comes twice.

Comment: I have added the echo just after this query, and it only echoes once :(

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your code might be run twice. To test, change your query to + and see if it would add two as you run your code.

> mysql_query("UPDATE ead_modulos SET slides = slides - 1 WHERE
>   id_modulo = '$id_modulo';");

to

> mysql_query("UPDATE ead_modulos SET slides = slides + 1 WHERE
>   id_modulo = '$id_modulo';");

Just for testing..

Also try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ead_modulos SET slides = slides - 1 WHERE id_modulo = '$id_modulo';");
exit();
```

Comment: Yes, it adds 2 if use the plus sign, I also added an echo to see if it was shown twice, but no, the echo text only shows once...

Comment: can you edit your post and let us see how you run the query along with the php codes?

Comment: I have tried something different, i got this query and pasted it on the index.php, right on the top, so it would run on every page opened for testing purposes... The problem persisted, if i load any page, it subtracts 2, if i comment this line, nothing happens!

Comment: I added a code to e-mail me the result, to my surprise, i receive 2 e-mails, for some obscure reason the page is loaded 2 times every time...

Comment: The query is ok, the entire site is loading twice, i have to review the entire code, wich consists of several pages and A LOT of lines of code... Thanks for your help!